# Plastics for food packaging

Tags: plastics, food-chemistry

There are many types of plastics that can be used for food packaging, for example:

- Polyethylene terephthalate (PET)
- Polyethylene (PE)
- Polyvinyl chloride (PVC)
- Polypropylene (PP)

What are the differences between them?
Which one is most suitable for packaging pastries, for example, biscuits?

Comment: Not for your question but only for the title "plastics-for-food-packaging": some fruit ripen (rotten) faster when in contact with ethylene, which ripening fruits produce. Putting those in airtight plastic bags is not a good idea. That's why some plastic packing for fruits have deliberately made holes.

Answer (score 2):

This question is a little bit broad, but thankfully, there are many resources available.

In answer to part of your question

> Which one is most suitable for packaging pastries, for example, biscuits?

The Natural Resources Defense Council webpage [Food Storage Containers](http://www.nrdc.org/living/shoppingwise/food-storage-containers.asp), they state that the safest plastics are PET, HDPE, LDPE, and PP.

For comparing the various types of plastic, the [Plasticology 101](http://www.containerandpackaging.com/info/plasticology.asp) website compares the types of plastic according to:

- Temperature tolerances
- Clarity
- Chemical, scratch and impact resistance
- Rigidity
- Food contact acceptability
- Recyclable material

They suggest that PET, HDPE, PVC, LDPE, PP and PS are suitable for food, but temperature tolerances would be a major factor in what food they store.  Another chemical comparison that needs to be considered for the storage of food is information about the $\ce{O2}$, $\ce{N2}$, $\ce{CO2}$ gas and moisture transmission rates are included in Evergreen's document [The barrier performance of common plastic film](http://www.evergreen-packaging.com/en/uploadfile/201111/20111122180814336.pdf).

Specifically for biscuits, and any other baked goods, according to sevral websites, it depends on what the ingredients are - things to consider are the dairy content, whether the plastic will react with some of the ingredients etc.